# ScriptRunner source other scripts

Tags: java, mysql

I have several sql scripts looking like,

test.sql:

```
source a.sql
source b.sql
source c.sql
```

a.sql:

```
select * from a;
```

b.sql:

```
select * from b;
```

c.sql:

```
select * from c;
```

now I have to run test.sql from Java. First I tried to run it with JDBC, then I found out that running such a script can be done more easily with the ScriptRunner from ibatis.

```
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn);

runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.sql")));
```

but it seems that the ScriptRunner only supports simple SQL like select, insert, update. Executing "source xxx" will throw an error.

Does anybody know if there is a way to run such a script in Java?

Comment: Do you know what [`JDBC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) is?

Comment: @PM77-1 sorry, I think I described it wrong. I first try to use JDBC to execute all the sql, then I found out running sql scripts can be more easily done with ScriptRunner, so I switched to ScriptRunner